# React Datepicker input state not changing?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datetime

I have a multi-step form with child form components. On one of the components, I'm trying to implement [YouCanBookMe DatePicker](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime).

Now, when I try to update the state of datepicker's value like I do with other regular text inputs, the state does not get updated. If I typed the date, the state gets updated, but not when I actually select the date from the picker. I'm really clueless why. Can any of you point out why it doesn't?

Your help is greatly appreciated. I'm new to React and I've tried 3 different Datepicker libraries and I'm slowly going insane, because none seems to work or I'm not able to transform it to a Parent-Child structure. Thanks!

Parent:

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      wants_interview_date: moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY")
   }
  }
  
 handleChange(field) {
    return (evt) => this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
 }
 
 render(){
    return <FormStep8
        wants_interview_date={this.state.wants_interview_date}
        onDateChange={this.handleChange('wants_interview_date')} />;
 }
```

Child Component:

```js
render() {
  <Datetime
    timeFormat={false}
    dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
    inputProps={{id: 'wants_interview_date', onBlur: this.props.onDateChange, value: this.props.wants_interview_date}} //To get the regular HTML input props
  />
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `evt` ?

Comment: @MuratK. I don't. I don't fully understand that StateChange method, but it works with normal text inputs. I got it from [this tutorial](https://goshakkk.name/wizard-form-collect-info/)

Answer (score 2):

The good friends at [Reactiflux](https://www.reactiflux.com/) helped me solve the issue. Apparently `Moment.js` was returning an Object on `handleChange` and therefore the state was not showing anything. The output needed to use the `_d Moment.js` method. Here is the correct `handleChange` method:

```
handleDateChange(field) {
    return evt => {
      const value = evt._d;
      this.setState({ wants_interview_date: value });
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet works fine for me, import DateTime (capital T)

```
import DateTime from 'react-datetime'; 

<DateTime name="newapp_time" 
onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ newapp_time: moment(e).toJSON() }) }} />
```

the result is a timestamp in this case

Comment: Would it work if you update the state with the use of props? Because that is my current issue

Comment: do u mean, setting initial state with props?

Comment: You said, if you pick the date from picker, then the state is not working, right? If thats the case, my solution would work. I also faced issues with datetime packages. But this one works fine for me. Please,Try it and let me know. :)

Comment: I am trying to set the state from a child component. The state is set on the parent component. And the state is not being updated. That's my issue

Comment: Im sorry, Im unable to completely understand you code, because there are mistakes, like (changes here)=> 1.this.handleChange.bind(this,'wants_interview_date')

Comment: 2.handleChange(field,evt) {
     this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
 }

Comment: Added your changes, value and state are still not changing